# How do I add an element within an element? (ES6)

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I'm attempting to add an element by using:

```
let el = `<div></div>`;
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

I noticed that `el` is shown as a 'string' in console.log. Should I be adding the element via `createElement` instead?

code:

```
let topPos = (Math.random() * 100) + '%'
let leftPos = (Math.random() * 100) + '%'
let bubbleMd = `
    <div class="bubble bubble-md"></div>
`;
let layer = document.getElementsByClassName('layer3')

layer.appendChild(bubbleMd).setAttribute(
    'style',`top: ${topPos}; left: ${leftPos};`
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) yes, you need to use createElement because appendChild expects a HTMLElement not a string, b) layer is a nodelist, so has no appendChild method

So:

```
let topPos = (Math.random() * 100) + '%'
let leftPos = (Math.random() * 100) + '%'
let bubbleMd = createElemnt('div');
bubbleMd.classList.add('bubble', 'bubble-md');
bubbleMd.style=`top: ${topPos}; left: ${leftPos};`;
let layer = document.getElementsByClassName('layer3')[0]; // note the [0]
layer.appendChild(bubbleMd);
```

Comment: So I used `document.createElement` and now I'm getting a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined`. When I console.log I get the following:

`bubbleMd: [object HTMLDivElement]
layer3: undefined`

Comment: what does `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('layer3').length)` output?

Comment: `console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('layer3').length)` outputs `0`

Comment: so that's your problem - I can't fix that in my answer since a) you never mentioned that in the question, and b) you haven't shown any HTML :p